# addview to layout

Tags: android, layout

I have create class that extend View, i`m trying to layout.addView(somthing) in layout, not exception is trowed.

layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

class

```
public class Navigator extends View {
Context context;
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.navigator);

public Navigator(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

TextView tab1 = new TextView(context);
tab1.setText("blah");
PROBLEM-> layout.addView(tab1);
}
```

Comment: I have try and whit findViewById(R.id.****) but its not work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding your extended view to an Activity?

Because you are modifying your view but I can't see where are you attaching your "Navigator" view.

Another thing is that your RelativeLayout declared on the XML has no ID, so you will never find a RelativeLayout with R.id.navigator id.

Comment: :) its fine whit id, i add the needed row but it not work. I call this class in my MainActivity. i have debug and the problem is in addView() its look like can`t connect whit the layout... How to add view in layout in non activity class?

Comment: You need to set layout_width and height of your new TextView, otherwise it will have 0dp on both sizes.

tx.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams....));

Comment: No, i have try and did`t work, its all fine to add textview from my MainActivity class but in non activity class it can`t connect to layout.